# Next.js: how to go to parent page from current child page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

my apology if this is a super dumb question, I'm a beginner of Next.js and React.js.

I have some basic knowledge that in Next.js, we can create a hierarchy of pages, and the path of a xx_page.js file would be the url route for that js file, [as described in the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction).

For example, my pages are structured as follows,

```sh
pages  // a folder
| -- home  // a folder
|     | -- index.js  // a file, the code for route "/home"
      | -- sports  // a folder
      |     | -- index.js  // a file, the code for route "/home/sports"
      |     | -- football.js  // a file, the code for "/home/sports/football"
```

Suppose the current page is at route "xxx.com/home/sports/football", and on the page there is a "Back" button, after clicking it, we should go back to "xxx.com/home/sports".

I failed to figure out a proper way to do that, mostly what I found by Google are about going back to the previous page, and not what I want.

Please give me some help about how to do it in Next.js, thanks!

Comment: Do you want to go back to the parent page always.?
what are you clicking, browser back or back link inside window .?

Comment: @NaveenSetty Good questions! I always want to go back to parent, just like "level up" index. Click a button named "Back", not browser back.

Answer (score 1):

There's no correct definition of "Back", so you have to define it. For your button, if you do the following

```
      <Link href="/home/sports">
        <a className="back">←</a>
      </Link>
```

It should behave exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, this can do the job and go back to parent "/home/sports", but that's hard-coded as a value to `href`, what if I changed the file structure by add another folder say "/home/extra/sports/football.js"? Then I have to change this hard-coded `href` value as well, right? If so, that's not good.

Comment: there's no magic of back as i mentioned. You have to put this url somewhere, if not in the href, you have to put in the child or parent component. There's no other way.

Comment: Thanks for your comment again. I see, initially I thought by the structure of `pages` folder and files, NextJS would know who is whose parent or child, now according to you comment, NextJS doesn't, right?

Comment: You have a good point, i'm sure `nextJS` knows. because you can use `getStaticPaths` to create dynamic paths. But normally they assume you can get this info from `window.location.href`. so most likely this info isn't passed to the prop. I don't know, you have a good point.

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking to remove the last part of the URL, you can do the below

```
let a = window.location.href.split("/")
a.pop();
window.location.href = a.join("/");
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of this solution as well, but I feel it's not a good one, because say some url might be ".../parent/child/:id", and only strip the last part (i.e. "id") and end up with ".../parent/child", this is not correct at all, since it should be ".../parent".

Comment: @avocado How would you know what's a child and what's a parent if that's the case?